# Force internal wrapping on child div

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a design that includes dynamically generated rows that contain a company name, a short status, and a set of navigation buttons.  I am trying to configure the CSS to ensure that the status and navigation buttons remain nowrap, and if needed, the name of the company to wrap.

```css
.row {
  background: #ececec;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100%;
}

.name {
  background-color: red;
  width: auto !important;
  line-height: 2.5em;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

.status {
  color: white;
  padding: 3px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-left: 1em;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.nav {
  background-color: #ddd;
  width: 400px;
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="name">Kind of a long silly name but you know how that is
    <span class="status"> Status can be a pain</span>
  </div>
  <div class="nav">
    Navigation
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/chipsterva69/2f63wd1k/)

Ideally, we would like the content in 'name' to wrap in smaller browsers.

Here is a quick sketch of what we would like the code to do:
[image]

Currently, as coded, when the window is narrowed, the navigation div slides under the name div.  Have tried floats, position:absolute, position:fixed...  I know the answer is in there somewhere, but I can't figure out the correct combination.

Navigation is not a fixed width (unlike this example), since the presence of links, and which links, is dependent on code elsewhere.

If it matters, we are using Bootstrap 3.3.7 and jQuery 3.3.1.

Comment: What do you expect the layout to be on smaller screens? Can you put up a quick drawing?

Comment: @disinfor - just added a mockup of what we hope to accomplish in smaller screens.  Thanks for asking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use `flex-box` to do this:

```css
.row {
  background: #ececec;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.name {
  background-color: red;
  width: auto !important;
  line-height: 2.5em;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  justify-content: space-between;
  display: flex;
  align-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.status {
  color: white;
  padding: 3px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-left: 1em;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.nav {
  background-color: #ddd;
  text-align: right;
  position: relative;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">

  <div class="name">Kind of a long silly name but you know how that is
    <span class="status"> Status can be a pain</span>
  </div>

  <div class="nav">
    Navigation Navigation Navigation Navigation
  </div>

</div>
```

Here's a fiddle to play with:
https://jsfiddle.net/tfqek0nx/2/

Comment: Worked great, @disinfor - thanks a million.  I obviously need to better understand flex box.

Comment: `flex` is pretty fun once you get the hang of it. Good luck!